# Requirements to run SQL Server on other computers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose that I've created a project using MS SQL Server.

Now if somebody asks me to run my application on their brand new PC, should I install the entire SQL Server management studio on their computer? Or are there any other choices?

Please note that I just want to run my app (.exe template) not to debug it or anything else.

Comment: The "server" in SQL Server means that other computers can connect to yours.  Well, unless you have a freebie version, where such connections are more limited.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Forgive my ignorance Gordon, do you mean any time the client wants to run the app, my computer must be turned on? (Just because my computer acts as a server)

Comment: MS SQL Server  is usually deployed on a stand alone machine usually called (server), Then apps connects to sql server on that machine to perform sql related task. if you want a lightweight database that is deployed with your app on client machine then use SQLLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is intended for standalone use on a PC, you can include the redistributable version of SQL Server Express in your installer.  It's a limited but functional version of SQL server intended to be included with application programs like yours free of charge.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

If your application program is designed for either shared or standalone use, and you have time to polish up your installer, you can ask your users whether they want to use a shared SQL Server instance.  That will let you skip the installation of SQL Server Express when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't need SQL server or management studio , however they a database driver to access the server. ADO, ODBC and JDBC are the types of drivers you would look at. This depends on the language you wrote your application in and the connection string.

You clients would use the server's address and connect to it using the driver which is specified in a connection string. See the examples below:

.Net Framework Data Provider For SQL Server:

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

SQL Server Native Client 11.0 OLE DB Provider:

`Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;`

If you application only connect to the database that you have a two-tier client server architecture. For the server to be reachable it needs to be on a network or network endpoint that the clients(people running your software) can see. The server needs to be on as well(your comments).